# Skipping hidden rows and only running macro on visible rows

Tags: vba, rows, hidden

I have the following vba code that I use in Excel 2007. It works perfectly. I would like to enhance this for users.

It presently hides all of the completed rows that users have submitted in a form. The code currently reviews all rows of submitted data and hides the row if the user has submitted all the necessary data. I would like to know where I can place a code to do this, but only on visible rows? Right now it goes through all of them each time the macro is run, re-reviewing past submissions that cleared the check. I just need it to review the new rows of data.

I am new to writing vba code so simple explaination or example of where to put that is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim lASTrOW As Long, C As Range
lASTrOW = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each C In Range("V4:V" & lASTrOW)
     If C.Value = 0 Then
          C.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     ElseIf C.Value = "null" Then
          C.EntireRow.Hidden = False
     End If
Next
If C.Value = "null" Then
     MsgBox "Visible rows contain missing data. Review and update."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you need, try

```
For Each C In Range("V4:V" & lASTrOW).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```